# SwiftUI List crashes when deleting an item that was tapped before

Tags: ios, list, swiftui, delete-row, ios-navigationview

I have a List with Recipes in a NavigationView that navigate to the RecipeDetail, with is just a Detail View of the recipe. The List is declared like this:

```
NavigationView{
            List {
                Section(header: HStack {
                    Text("Rezepte")
                    Spacer()
                    self.addButton
                        .sheet(isPresented: self.$showingAddRecipeView) {
                            AddRecipe { recipe in
                                self.recipeStore.addRecipe(recipe: recipe)
                                self.recipeStore.showingAddRecipeView = false
                            }
                    }
                }) {
                    ForEach(recipeStore.recipes){ recipe in
                        NavigationLink(
                            destination: RecipeDetail(
                                recipe: self.$recipeStore.recipes[self.recipeStore.recipes.firstIndex(where: { self.recipeStore.selectedRecipe?.id == $0.id }) ?? 0],
                                creating: false,
                                addRecipe: nil,
                                dismiss: nil
                            ).environmentObject(self.recipeStore),
                            tag: recipe,
                            selection: self.$recipeStore.selectedRecipe
                        ) {
                            Card(recipe: recipe)
                        }.accessibility(identifier: recipe.name)
                    }
                    .onMove(perform: moveRecipes)
                    .onDelete(perform: deleteRecipes)
                }
                
                self.roomThemperatureSection
                self.importButton
                self.exportButton
                // self.donateButton
                self.aboutButton
            }
            .listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
            .navigationBarTitle("BrotApp", displayMode: .automatic)
            .navigationBarItems(trailing: EditButton().padding())
```

if I try to delete an recipe I have not clicked since I opened the App it just works but if I try to delete the recipe with the same gesture after clicking it and navigating back via the standart NavigationView Back Button it crashes with the following error:
`Fatal error: Index out of range: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-1103.2.25.8/swift/stdlib/public/core/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift, line 444 2020-06-22 10:27:19.798276+0200 BackApp[1604:40700] Fatal error: Index out of range: file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/swiftlang/swiftlang-1103.2.25.8/swift/stdlib/public/core/ContiguousArrayBuffer.swift, line 444`

here is the code for deleting the recipe:

```
   func deleteRecipes(at offsets: IndexSet){
        for index in offsets {
            recipeStore.deleteRecipe(at: index)
        }
   }

   func deleteRecipe(at index: Int) {
        if index < recipes.count {
            selectedRecipe = nil
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.75) {
                self.recipes.remove(at: index)
            }
            //select next
            #if os(macOS)
            if recipes.count > 1{
                guard let lastRecipe = recipes.last else { return }
                selectedRecipe = lastRecipe
            }
            #endif
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the reason for using selectedRecipe inside NavigationLink if you can just use recipe variable from ForEach cycle? And deleting inside DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter also looks strange.

Comment: Also it would be better to delete items using IndexSet, not indices one by one - as if you are deleting more than one index at once - it would work incorrectly.

Comment: I have to wait for the view to dissmiss first before i can delete the item